# Setting width of absolute div adds horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, position, scrollbar, absolute

I'm trying to center an absolute div and at the same time also set the width of this div, but apparently only one these two things is possible at the same time. I've managed to center the absolute div rather painlessly, but setting a `min-width` adds this useless horizontal scrollbar for no reason: https://jsfiddle.net/pietertje1/ze7472ge/

The weird thing is, if I stretch the div to its desired width by adding in a single line of characters, it behaves perfectly.

anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: there isn't a scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `min-width` rule is causing this. Expand your fiddle output window and you'll see it go away. If you need that `min-width` you can target elements and apply `overflow` rules to them. For example

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tthnvh9t/) - your example with this rule

### Edit

Per discussion, if you simply wish to center an element, apply the following `margin` rule

```
margin : 0 auto;
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eas3a4or/)

Comment: Yeah I know, but I just want to lose the horizontal scrolling completely, but I guess this is not possible?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I am not seeing any horizontal scroll bars in the example I supplied

Comment: That's correct, however it's still possible to scroll horizontally. (by clicking your mouse wheel for example). By adding overflow-x:hidden you're just hiding the scrollbar.

Comment: @user1870238 I'm not sure I still understand, and I can not replicate. `overflow-x: hidden` will not allow me to scroll horizontally. Can you share specifically which browser you are seeing this occur?

Comment: That also disables vertical scrolling, not what I want. Isn't it weird that it's so difficult to do something as mundane as centering and setting a width?

Comment: @user1870238 Is this what you want? Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eas3a4or/). If you just want to center something you can apply the following `margin` rule